# What is the best way to update cache in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, search, indexing, full-text-search

I'm using elasticsearch index as a cache table.
My document structure is the following:

```
{
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": False,
            "properties": {
                "query_str": {"type": "text"},
                "search_results": {
                    "type": "object", 
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "query_embedding": {
                    "type": "dense_vector",
                    "dims": 768,
                },
               
        }
    }
```

The cache search is performed via embedding vector similarity. So if the embedding of the new query is close enough to a cached one, it is considered as a cache hit, and `search_results` field is returned to the user.

The problem is that I need to update cached results about once an hour. I wish my service won't lose the ability to use cache efficiently while updating procedure, so I'm not sure which one of solutions is the best:

1. Sequentially **update** documents one-by-one, so the index won't be destroyed. The drawback of this solution I afraid is the fact, that every update causes index rebuilding, so the cache requests will become slow
2. Create entirely new index with new results and then somehow **swap** current cache index with the new one. The drawbacks I see are
   a) I've found no elegant way to swap indexes
   b) Users will get their cached resuts lately than in solution (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with #2 as everytime you update a document the cache is flushed.

There is an elegant way to swap indices:

You have an alias that points to your current index, you fill a new index with the fresh records, and then you point this alias to the new index.

Something like this:

1. Current index name is items-2022-11-26-001
2. Create alias items pointing to items-2022-11-26-001

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "items-2022-11-26-001",
        "alias": "items"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Create new index with fresh data items-2022-11-26-002
4. When it finishes, now point the items alias to items-2022-11-26-002

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "items-2022-11-26-001",
        "alias": "items"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "items-2022-11-26-002",
        "alias": "items"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

5. Delete items-2022-11-26-001

You run all your queries against "items" alias that will act as an index.

References:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: "everytime you update a document the cache is flushed" -
Do you mean some internal cache that elastic uses to speed up queries?

Why would it happen when I am updating only **disabled** field ```search_results``` (so there is no need in reindexing)?

Comment: Yes. Cache is invalidated everytime there is a change in a shard: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html#_cache_invalidation

Also global ordinals (the compute for aggregations) is rebuilt.

In practice there are no partial updates in Elasticsearch, when you update a document (even a single field) the whole document is being reindexed under the hood.

Comment: Are you sure that everything is so bad with partial updates? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html - docs say that "The enabled setting, which can be applied only to the top-level mapping definition and to object fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the _source field, but **it is not searchable or stored in any other way**". It seems logical not to re-index docs if changes took place only in non-indexed part

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different things but Elasticsearch documents are inmutable, that means everytime you change something the entire structure needs to be re-created.